# Why in the XOR exclusive operator does 1 and 1 =0?

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators

In the bitwise "^" exclusive operator 1 and 1=0 as shown below why is that?[image]

Comment: Because that's the way it's defined. What reason do you have for expecting a different result?

Comment: given that XOR is not the same and AND or OR, it makes sense it would get a different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, because it was defined that way. If you need the functionality of `OR` or `AND` then you can have that, but `XOR` does this.

It's sort of the quintessential computer science operator, so you better get used to it. =)

Philosophically, it's an *exclusive* `OR`. It does what you would expect from `OR` when one of the inputs is `1`, but requires that not both of them are `1` at the same time, hence the name exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

If either one or the other operand is 1 the result will be 1 but if both operands are 1 the result is 0. That is what makes it EXCLUSIVE OR.

Here is a nice explaination: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 0):

Before talking about XOR lets just discuss about AND , OR gates/operation

AND is true when both inputs are true

OR is true when any of input is true

now lets just come to XOR using above logic

Mathematically XOR = [i can place negation so i used image here click here to watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImPXq.png)

and this is other image that shows how gates are arranged if you are familiar with logic gates 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpj9Y.png)
Hope this may help cheers